# Double integral - Change of Variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to evaluate this double integral, but I don't see any good change of variables (I tried polar, but it got really hairy):

$$
\iint_D \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy
$$
given $D = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \le 1, y>0\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this change of variable

$$\begin{array}{}
x = r \cos \theta +1 \\
y = r \sin \theta 
\end{array}
$$

and the Jacobian will be

$$
J=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\cos \theta & -r \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta &  r \cos \theta
\end{vmatrix}
=
r
$$

The equation of the semi-circle in new coordinates will be

$$\begin{array}{}
x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\ 
(r \cos \theta + 1)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2 =1 \\
r^2 + 2 r \cos \theta + 1 = 1 \\
r=-2 \cos \theta
\end{array}$$

Also, the description of your domain $D$ in new coordinates will be

$$D = \{(r,\theta): 0 \le \theta \le \pi , 0 \le r \le -2 \cos \theta \}$$

and hence your integral becomes

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{-2 \cos \theta} r \cdot r dr d\theta
   =\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{-2 \cos \theta} r^2 dr d\theta$$

I think you can go on now. :)

Comment: But what about the limits of integration? $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$ and so does $y$, and I couldn't find a appropriate limits.

Comment: Yes, the limit are interesting! :) Shall I write the whole answer? :)

Comment: That would be helpful :)

Comment: @ViníciusLopesSimões: Take a look at the new answer. :)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot @H.R. !!!

Comment: @ViníciusLopesSimões: You are welcome. :)

Comment: Note that this change of variable amounts to first translating to place the center of the circle at the origin and then converting to polar.

Comment: @amd: Yes, you are right. :)

Comment: H.R how do the limit make sense. $r$ is positive but still in your limit it goes from $0$ to $-2\cos \theta$ and also when $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$ the integral becomes $0$.

Comment: i guess the final answer should be $$2\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_0^{-2\cos\theta}r^2drd\theta$$